# How can I authenticate web socket connection in postman?

Tags: python, django, websocket, postman, django-channels

This is my ASGI file:
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
import os
import app.routing
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

```
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")

application = get_asgi_application()

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http': get_asgi_application(),
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            app.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

This is my routing.py file:

from django.urls import path
from . import consumers

```
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path('ws/sc/', consumers.MySyncConsumer.as_asgi()),
    path('ws/ac/', consumers.MyASyncConsumer.as_asgi()),
    path('ws/test/', consumers.TestConsumer.as_asgi()),
    path('ws/scg/', consumers.MySyncGroupConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

This is my consumer file:

```
class MySyncConsumer(SyncConsumer):

def websocket_connect(self,event):
    print("Web socket connected", event)
    self.send({
        'type':'websocket.accept'
    })
    print("Channel layer ",self.channel_layer)
    print("Channel name", self.channel_name)
    async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)("test_consumer_group_1", self.channel_name)

def websocket_receive(self,event):
    print("Web socket recieved",event)
    print(event["text"])
    async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)("test_consumer_group_1", {
        'type':'chat.message',
        'message':event['text']
    })

#event handler, whuch is sending data to client
def chat_message(self,event):
    print('Event...', event) 
    print('Event...', event["message"])
    self.send({
        "type":"websocket.send",
        "text":event['message']
    })    

def send_notification(self, event):
    print("send_notification called")
    print('Event...', event['value']) 
    
    self.send({
        "type":"websocket.send",
        "text":event['value']
    })    

def websocket_disconnect(self,event):
    print("Web socket disconnect", event) 
    async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)("test_consumer_group_1", self.channel_name)
    raise StopConsumer()
```

How can I authenticate web socket connection in postman? I want to authenticate web socket connection so that self.scope["user"] returns currently logged in user in consumers.py. Otherwise it returns an anonymous user.

[image]